# Find missing number in the transformation

Tags: number-property

Can you find the missing number? This number has a single digit.

8 → 7

7 → 3

3 → 5

5 → ?

Good luck!

Comment: I think that you should familiarise yourself with this: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that 5 maps to

> 5

because it takes

> 5 segments to display the number 5 in a [seven segment display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display).
>
>  This fits the pattern for the other numbers:
>  - 8 takes 7 segments
>  - 7 takes 3 segments
>  - 3 takes 5 segments

Comment: Correct! Well done

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is

> 5 $\rightarrow$ 5

Reasoning

> For each digit count the number of lit segments in a seven-segment display of the number.
>  8 has 7 lit segments, 7 has 3, 3 has 5 and 5 has 5.